# Why is UITableViewCell text not aligned to the left?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why does this:

```
 Profile *showProfile = [[Profile alloc] init];

    showProfile = [profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([[showProfile lastName] length] > 0){
       NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [showProfile lastName], [showProfile firstName]];
       [[cell textLabel] setText:cellValue];

    }
```

Show the text on the UITableViewCell not on the left side. I can't post an image to show you, but this is killing me. The text seems to be more centered.

But if I do this:

```
Profile *showProfile = [[Profile alloc] init];

        showProfile = [profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([[showProfile lastName] length] > 0){
           NSString *cellValue = @"This is aligned properly";
           [[cell textLabel] setText:cellValue];

        }
```

The text is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your lastname doesn't have any whitespaces in front of it? Try trimming the string like this:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[cellValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Also note that you currently allocate a Profile object that is never used! Instead of:

```
Profile *showProfile = [[Profile alloc] init];
showProfile = [profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

simply use this:

```
Profile *showProfile = [profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Otherwise you always first create a new profile object you never use, which takes time.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! That was exactly the problem and I had noticed that when I was logging out the object's "last name" to the console. I had tried to remove the whitespace but wasn't doing as nicely as what you showed - so obviously what I had done simply didn't work. Thank you so much for your help - my scalp thanks you as well.